# Can jquery mobile link to messenger(whatapps,wechat,or others)?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Can i create a link that can open other messenger(whatsapp,wechat,or others) on my device?

I also create a link that use normal sms to text message

```
document.location.href = "sms:" + $("#ContactNumber").val() + "?body=" + $("#SMSContent").val();
```

Is work well in sms but cannot detect other messenger apps on my device.

Is this possible to do on jquery mobile?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are on android's WebView.

If you do something as below it'll invoke your default dialler in  your mobile

`<a href="tel:555-123-4567">`

Also you can overide your method as below to invoke custom Intents

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url)
{
    if(isNumber)
    {
        //Get the number from the URL
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:12345"));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Read the [documentation to tweak more](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

Read more at about URI standards[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme)